# Setting IBM Streams instance properties and bringing that to effect without restarting the instance

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-streams, ibm-infosphere

I have to set some instance properties for working on consistent region projects. I set those properties, but they got reflected only when I restarted the instance, which obviously resulted in all the running jobs getting cancelled.
I have 100s of jobs running which I cannot disturb, but want to set the 'checkpointRepositoryConfiguration', etc on the instance that is required to work with consistent regions.
Is there a way I can set these instance properties without restarting the instance or if at all I have to restart the instance, is there a way I can prevent the jobs running on that instance from getting cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we do not support dynamically updating both properties.  We have a task for this enhancement, but it is not supported so far.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘both’ property? Both refers to?